# Where to define CUDA kernels in a program with multiple source files

Tags: c++, cuda

See question in bold below.

I have a functional C++ program that I want to rewrite using CUDA. I have acquired a reasonable understanding of how to use CUDA from various NVIDIA tutorials and a Udacity course. But my problem is: In all examples in such tutorials, they always use as an example a program with a very simple structure. Usually, it's just one single `.cu` file that contains various kernel definitions followed by a `main()` function that does some stuff, allocates some device memory, and runs the kernels. While these simple examples help me understand how to use CUDA, they don't help me understand how to integrate CUDA code into a more complex program containing classes. This is a question about how to structure a CUDA program.

Let's get concrete:

I have a serial particle filter program consisting of the following source files:

- `main.cpp` to run the main program
- `particle_filter.h` and `particle_filter.cpp` contain a class that contains all the logic of the particle filter
- Some other header files that are irrelevant to my question

A lot of the computation happening in the particle filter class is a perfect use case for parallelization. Inside many of the methods of the particle filter class, I want to replace loops with kernel calls.

My question is:

**Where should the definitions of those kernels go?**

Thanks for any help

As per the comment below, here is the code of one method defined in `particle_filter.cpp`. The method initializes the particle filter object. I want to replace the `for` loop inside the method with a kernel call. Where do I define the kernel? Does the kernel definition become another method of the class? Or should I define the kernel elsewhere? Should the kernels even be defined within the same source file or in a separate one? I know it is ultimately up to me, but what are the best practices here?

```
void ParticleFilter::init(double x, double y, double theta, double std[]) {

  // Set the number of particles
  num_particles = 100;

  // Declare the random generator
  default_random_engine gen;

  // Extract the standard deviations for x, y, and theta
  double std_x = std[0];
  double std_y = std[1];
  double std_theta = std[2];

  // Creates normal distributions for x, y and theta.
  normal_distribution<double> dist_x(x, std_x);
  normal_distribution<double> dist_y(y, std_y);
  normal_distribution<double> dist_theta(theta, std_theta);

  // Create the vector to contain the `num_particles` particles
  particles = vector<Particle>(num_particles);

  // Create the vector to contain the weight for each particle
  weights = vector<double>(num_particles);

  // Loop over the particle vector and initialize each particle with the initial (x,y,theta) position
  // passed in the arguments with added Gaussian noise and weight 1
  for (int i = 0; i < num_particles; i++) {

    particles[i].id = i; // Set this particle's ID
    particles[i].x = dist_x(gen); // Generate a random value from `dist_x` to set as this particle's x position
    particles[i].y = dist_y(gen); // Generate a random value from `dist_y` to set as this particle's y position
    particles[i].theta = dist_theta(gen); // Generate a random value from `dist_theta` to set as this particle's orientation theta
    particles[i].weight = 1.0; // Set the initial weight for all particles to 1

  }

  is_initialized = true;

}
```

Comment: This is a very difficult question to answer without being able to see your code.

Comment: @Chiel I added the code of one method of the particle filter class to make the question more concrete.

Comment: I would create a kernel function that is called at the place of the `for` loop. Have a look at other codes that use CUDA.

Comment: @Chiel Your wording is ambiguous: Are you saying you would define the kernel inside the method and then call it right after? I.e. have both the kernel definition and its call inside the method, replacing the for loop? Thanks for your help!

Comment: Ah sorry. I would define them at the top of the file in an anonymous namespace. Here, as an example: https://github.com/microhh/microhh/blob/master/src/advec_2.cu

Comment: A kernel, by itself, cannot be a class member (you can call a kernel from a class member function, but you cannot define a kernel as a class member function).  Beyond that, I think the question of where to define it will be mostly dictated by your project organization, not any over-arching concepts.  You might define it anywhere you would define helper functions to be called from class member functions.  If you intend for that kernel to be only callable from that class, then you could define the kernel in the class implementation, before the member function(s) that use it.

Comment: @RobertCrovella thanks for your comment! Even though it should be dictated by my project organization, it is still very useful when more experienced coders like you mention a few alternatives that might make sense. If I put the kernel definitions at the top of the class implementation, would you put them inside an anonymous namespace as Chiel suggested? I mean, there's no downside to doing that, is there? Thanks a lot!

Comment: What i would recommend is to isolate cpp releated code from the cuda code as much as possible. If the kernel functions are to be used inside the cpp code one can use a helper function which can be defined in the `.cu` file along with the kernels and the function signature in a separate `.h`. The helper functions will be the function that decides the block/grid sizes and the kernel call sequences etc. This will help the developer to even use `g++` for compiling non cuda releated codes and `nvcc` only for kernels as well

Answer (score 3):

The program you describe is still very simple (which is why I'm able to venture an answer... that also ignores your code).

What I think you need to do is the following:

1. Determine which parts of your program involve a lot of parallelizable work (irrespective of how it's structured now; think of the entirety of the work abstraction that is done.)
2. Determine whether the data fits entirely in GPU global memory.

   2.1 If it does, initializations might be relevant to do on the GPU as well.

   2.2 If it doesn't, it's less likely to be worth it to initialize things on the GPU, but if you do it on the CPU it still needs to be effective and multithreaded, otherwise maybe the GPU is relevant anyway just for simplicity's sake.
3. Have a `.cu` file for each kernel (and possibly `.cuh` for device-side functions which the kernel calls), or perhaps closely related group of kernels. (Also remember that same functionality with different types = single templated kernel in a single file.)
4. Have some wrapper/bridge/whatever piece of code, with a purely-C++ header but a CUDA implementation, which actually launches stuff (you have to cross from normal C++ to CUDA somewhere). Now, it's likely other people have implemented something like that which you could use, but you could also write something simple yourself. You may need such a wrapper to exist per-kernel or it could be something central.
5. Your main.cpp includes the wrapper header(s), and launches kernels using it; this works because you link the CUDA-compiled and host-compiler-compiled code together.

I hope I'm making sense without concrete examples.

---

#### Partial concrete example

The trickiest point in the above advice is definitely no. 4. here's what I use in my own code to "bridge" normally-compiled and NVCC-compiled code:

- A [launch mechanism](https://github.com/eyalroz/cuda-api-wrappers/blob/master/src/cuda/api/kernel_launch.cuh) which compiles different with a regular compiler and with NVCC.
- A [kernel wrapper](https://github.com/eyalroz/libgiddy/blob/master/src/cuda/kernel_wrapper.cuh) which uses the launch mechanism, and is usable from regular C++ code.

<sub>Note that the first file is part of lightweight Modern-C++-ish [CUDA Runtime API wrapper library](https://github.com/eyalroz/cuda-api-wrappers/) of mine, which makes the host-side coding more convenient in several ways.</sub>

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Question about your third point: I have this source file `particle_filter.cpp` that implements the particle filter class. The methods of this class do all the computation. Each method does stuff that can be parallelized, so each method will call a kernel or two. Why is it better to define the kernels in separate `.cu` files? My idea was to just rename the `particle_filter.cpp` file to `particle_filter.cu` and define all the kernels at the top of the file in an anonymous namespace. Is that not a good idea?

Comment: @Alex: Well, the kernels need to be compiled with NVCC, but your purely host-side code typically doesn't. So separate `.cu` and `.cpp` files makes sense if you compile them with different compilers. As for separating kernels into different files - that's basically personal preference / coding convention.

Comment: Also note that if you try to build everything using `nvcc`, there are limitations of the compiler driver compared to `g++`. For example `nvcc` does not provide `-W` option